Examples of Tensoring over Space in $\infty$-Category
In Higher Topos Theory by Jacob Lurie, for an $\infty$-category $C$, one can define the canonical tensoring over the $\infty$-category of spaces as a $\infty$-colimit.
If $X\in \mathrm{Spc}$ and $c\in C$, define $X\otimes c:=\mathrm{colim}(X\xrightarrow{const_c} C)$.
I have seen examples of such tensoring for several $\infty$-category, such the category of chain complexes over commutative ring $R$, where the tensoring is $C_\bullet(X ; c)$,  or in the category of spectra, which is $\Sigma^{\infty}_{+}X \land c$.
I do not know much about (co)limit in $\infty$-category besides merely the definition, and I am curious how these results were calculated. I would appreciate it if someone could lead me through the calculation of the above examples or offer some references to read for me on this subject.

I don't think there's really going to be an answer other than "check that the claimed formula works". Before going to higher categories, can you convince yourself that tensoring a module $M$ by a set $X$ gives the direct sum $M^{\oplus X}$ (i.e. $X$-many copies of $M$)?

I think the key technical point to note is the characterization of spaces as the free $\infty$-category on one object, meaning for a category $C$ with colimits:
$$
\text{Fun}^L(\text{Spc},C) \simeq \text{Fun}(*,C) \simeq C
$$
where $\text{Fun}^L$ are the colimit preserving functors and the equivalence is given by evaluating on the point/ left Kan extension. This you can find in chapter 5 of HTT.
So for a category $C$ admitting colimits and an object $c \in C$, we get a unique colimit preserving functor $- \otimes c:\text{Spc} \to C$, determined by taking the point to c.
Now we only need to check that the different descriptions you gave above are all of this form:
For $\varinjlim_X c$ it should be clear that $\varinjlim_* c =c$. Furthermore this is just the formula for left Kan extension, so it preserves colimits. (I don't know if there is a more direct way to see this without the result above.)
For the example with spectra it's part of the construction of the symmetric monoidal structure that $\Sigma^\infty_+$ preserves colimits and is symmetric monoidal, and the smash product preserves colimits. So it follows that $\Sigma^\infty_+ X \wedge c$ preserves colimits in $X$ and sends the point to $\Sigma^\infty_+ * \wedge c\simeq \mathbb{S} \wedge c \simeq c$.
